# Alignment in an enumerate environment using “\hspace” and "\hphantom" commands

Tags: tex-core, enumerate

I give a display of the first three problems from a multiple-choice test in algebra. The choices in the first problem are displayed using a `tabbing` environment, and the choices in the second and third problems are set using an `enumerate` environment. I would like to get displays for the choices using only one environment in accordance to the following specifications.

The (invisible) left margin of the environment should be at a distance of `\hphantom{\noindent {\bf 1.) }}` from the left margin.

Since I am using the default font size  of 10pt, the inter-line distance is 12pt. (A typesetter said that the ratio of line height to font size equal to 1.2 leaves enough space between lines for a harmonious look.)  The choices in the second problem are fractions set in `displaystyle` mode.  What should the inter-line spacing be in that case?  I think the inter-line spacing used in an `align` environment or a  `gather` environment would be appropriate.

The first columns in the first and third problems are to be aligned with the column in the second problem.

In the first and third problems, the choices in the first row should be `a.)` and `b.)`, the choices in the second row should be `c.)` and `d.)`, and the choice in the third row should be `e.)`.  Also, the spacing between the columns should be `2.5in`.  How do I specify this using `\begin{multicols}{2}` before an environment that makes tables?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}



\noindent {\bf 1.) }$A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, and $F$ are six points in the Cartesian plane. A line is drawn if, and only if, it contains two of these points. If no line contains three of the given points, how many lines are drawn?
\begin{tabbing}
\noindent\hphantom{{\bf 1.) }} \= \hspace{2.5in} \= \kill
\> {\bf{a.) }}15    \> {\bf{b.) }}18 \\
\> {\bf{c.) }}20    \> {\bf{d.) }}30 \\
\> {\bf{e.) }}36
\end{tabbing}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent {\bf 2.) }A rectangular pen enclosing 4,000 square meters is to be made from split rail fencing along the span of one side of a barn. The pen is to be divided into three smaller, rectangular regions with more split rail fencing. If the side of this barn bordering the pen is $y$ meters long, how many meters of split rail fencing is needed to make the pen?
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries \alph*.), itemsep=\baselineskip, itemindent=0mm]
  \item $y + \dfrac{4,000}{y}$
  \item $y + \dfrac{16,000}{y}$
  \item $y + \dfrac{16,000}{3y}$
  \item $3y + \dfrac{8,000}{3y}$
  \item $3y + \dfrac{16,000}{3y}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\vskip0.25in


\noindent {\bf 3.) }Some bacteria are being cultured in a laboratory. The population of the bacteria in the culture $t$ days after the culture began is modeled by the function
\begin{equation*}
P(t) = 3,000 \left(2^{\frac{t}{4}}\right) .
\end{equation*}
By how many bacteria does the population increase from the end of the $4^{\mathrm{th}}$ day to the end of the $16^{\mathrm{th}}$ day?
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries \alph*.), itemsep=\baselineskip, itemindent=0mm]
\item 6,000 \\
\item 24,000 \\
\item 36,000 \\
\item 42,000 \\
\item 48,000
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please consider reading [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Comment: You're using `itemsep=\baseline` instead of `itemsep=\baselineskip`

Comment: @egreg  I use `itemsep=\baselineskip` in the first problem of the second display.

Comment: @user74973 Yes, but you get errors that you shouldn't disregard.

Comment: @egreg  I just edited the code in the post - replacing `\baseline` with `\baselineskip`.  Do you know why the inter-line spacing is much bigger than the baseline spacing?

Comment: You have `\dfrac` in inline formulas.

Comment: @egreg  I edited the code.  The inter-line spacing is too big in the `enumerate` environment in which the entries are integers.

Comment: @egreg  What is the inter-line spacing in text mode?  Is it `0.6ex`?  If it is `0.6ex`, that is what I would like to have for the inter-line spacing between the rows in every `enumerate` environment.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with the `tasks` package, which emulates a multicolumn enumerate environment. Demo with first your original `tabbing` environment, then two `tasks` environments. A few words of explanation: `label-offset` is the distance between label and item; `item-indent` is like `leftmargin` in a list and we have the relation: `item-indent=label-width+item-indent`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{label-format=\bfseries, label-offset=0.85em,counter-format =tsk[a].) , column-sep =8pt, item-indent=4em, after-item-skip=0ex plus 0.25ex, after-skip=3ex}

\begin{document}

\noindent {\bf 1.) }$A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, and $F$ are six points in the Cartesian plane. A line is drawn if, and only if, it contains two of these points. If no line contains three of the given points, how many lines are drawn?
\begin{tabbing}
  \noindent\hphantom{{\bf 1.) }} \= \hspace{2.5in} \= \kill
  \> {\bf{a.) }}15 \> {\bf{b.) }}18 \\
  \> {\bf{c.) }}20 \> {\bf{d.) }}30 \\
  \> {\bf{e.) }}36
\end{tabbing}
\vskip0.25in

\noindent {\bf 2.) }A rectangular pen enclosing 4,000 square meters is to be made from split rail fencing along the span of one side of a barn. The pen is to be divided into three smaller, rectangular regions with more split rail fencing. If the side of this barn bordering the pen is $y$ meters long, how many meters of split rail fencing is needed to make the pen?
\begin{tasks}[after-item-skip=0.6ex plus 0.5ex](2)
  \task $ y + \dfrac{4,000}{y} $
  \task $ y + \dfrac{16,000}{y} $
  \task $ y + \dfrac{16,000}{3y} $
  \task $ 3y + \dfrac{8,000}{3y} $
  \task $ 3y + \dfrac{16,000}{3y} $
\end{tasks}

\noindent {\bf 1.) }$A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, and $F$ are six points in the Cartesian plane. A line is drawn if, and only if, it contains two of these points. If no line contains three of the given points, how many lines are drawn?
\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task 15
  \task 18
  \task 20
  \task 30
  \task 36
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I may prefer using the package `tasks`.  The choices in the second problem should be `a.)`, `b.)`, `c.)`, `d.)`, and `e.)` - you are missing the periods.  (I guess that this edit may be made.)   What is the inter-line spacing?  I guess it is measured in units of `ex`. I am guessing from your specified option `after-item-skip=0.6ex plus 0.5ex` that it is `0.6ex`.  What is `plus 0.5ex`?

Comment: Here are the periods. The specified option `after-item-skip`  is the rubber length that is *added* to the normal `baselineskip`. The default value I chose is `0ex plus 0.25ex`, but with rows of fractions it was unsufficient, so I locally changed it. The `plus` part indicates how much stretching is accepted in order to fill the page. There also could be a `minus` part. Of course these `plus/minus` parts (typical of co-called rubber lengths) are useless if the `\raggedbottom` directive was enabled. The default is `\flushbottom`.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the display that I want.  My only concern is that I have not heard of the `tasks` package.  If I want to modify the displays of the choices, I wouldn't know how to do it.

Comment: I won't need the stretching to fill the page because I will use `\vfill\pagebreak`.  Is the  inter-line spacing in text mode `0.6ex`?  Does the `after-item-skip` option determine the distance between rows?  If it does, shouldn't `after-item-skip=0ex` determine that there is no distance between rows?

Comment: No: it determines nothing is *added* to the normal `\baselineskip` (which is ~ 3ex). As I said I set the default to 0ex, plus a very small amount (0.25 ex ~ 1/12\baselineskip). The 0.6ex in my example is just an optional argument, which you may remove (in my opinion the spacing for this particular case will be too tight, that's all). The options are explained in the doc,§ 4 ‘Available options’, pp. 8-11. For your information, `tasks` was formerly part of the `exsheets` package, which you may know, and has been recently made independent.

Comment: How did you get the columns in all three problems to align?   The first table uses the `tabbing` environment.  Specifying `\hspace{2.5in}` gets the distance between the left edges of the two columns to be 2.5 inches?  In the `tasks` environment, I think the alignment is at the right edge after `a.)`, `c.)`, and `e.)` in the first column and after the right edge after `b.)` and `d.)` in the second column.

Comment: I simply adjusted the `item-indent` and `label-offset` to fit your jayout with the tabbing environment. I added some explanations about these parameters/keys in my answer.

Comment: Are you saying that aligned the columns visually?  In the tabbing environment, I have 2.5 inches between the columns.  I don't see that any of your specification are 2.5 inches.  You specify `item-indent=4em` - much less than 2.5 inches.

Comment: Please provide the link to the `tasks` package.  I am prone to use the `numerate` package for at least two reasons - I have used it, and it is a popular package on this site for those needing to make lists. used it, and it is a popular package on this site for those needing to make lists.

Comment: Here is [one](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tasks/). However I didn't say you shouldn't use the `enumitem` package Simply this one is designed for your problem. Note you should install it via your package manager, as it is part of TeX Live as well as of MiKTeX.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  If I do not get the other package to give me the display that I want, I'll surely use `tasks`.  As you said, it does give me the display that I want.

Comment: Don't I just put `\usepackage{tasks}` in the preamble?  What is `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`?

Comment: For my code, `tasks` is enough. All other packages but one were in your code, so I let them as they are. Last, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is mine. It is about the encoding of the .tex file. Most modern editors use `unicode` by default, and unless you type pure ascii (no accented characters), it must be declared to LaTeX. That is especially important for languages with diacritics.